# IMO 2010 N2: Find all pairs $(m,n)$ of nonnegative integers for which $m^2 + 2 \cdot 3^n = m\left(2^{n+1} - 1\right).$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Find all pairs $(m,n)$ of nonnegative integers for which $m^2 + 2 \cdot 3^n = m\left(2^{n+1} - 1\right).$

I am not able to start , however I got solutions $(m,n)$  as $(6,3), (9,3), (9,5),$ or $(54,5)$... Can one help me? Thanks!

Comment: FYI, this is problem N$2$ (from Australia), with a solution given on page $66$ of [Mathematical Olympiad: 51st IMO Shortlisted Problems with Solutions](https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2010SL.pdf). Note it confirms the $4$ pairs you give are the only ones which satisfy the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We note that $m^2-m(2^{n+1}-1)+2\cdot3^n = 0$,  now this equation is supposed to have integer solutions, so it's discriminant $d$ must be a perfect square. $$\implies d^2 = (2^{n+1}-1)^2-4\cdot2\cdot3^n \iff (2^{n+1}-1-d)(2^{n+1}-1+d)=2^3\cdot3^n.$$
Now, both the factors sum to $2(2^{n+1}-1)$ and both of them must be of the form $2\cdot3^a$ and $4\cdot3^b$, where $a,b$ are non-negative integers with $a+b=n.$
\begin{align*}
\implies2\cdot3^a+4\cdot3^b=2(2^{n+1}-1)\iff\boxed{3^a+2\cdot3^b=2^{a+b+1}-1}
\end{align*}

> **Motivation** (Classic; for below). The only positive integers that satisfy $|3^x-2^y|=1$ are $(x,y)=\{(1,1);(2,3);(1,2)\}.$

*Case 1*: $\boxed{\min(a,b)\leqslant2}.$ For $a=0: 3^b=2^b-1$; there is not solution from above. For $a=1: 3^b=2^{b+1}-2$, since $3^b\equiv 1,3 \pmod 4$, and as $b\geqslant 1 \implies 2^{b+1}-2 \equiv 2 \pmod4.$ Hence, no solutions in this case as well. Now, for $a=2$ we have:
$$3^2+2\cdot3^b=2^{b+3}-1\iff3^b=2^{b+2}-5.$$
$3^2\equiv 1 \pmod 9 \implies 3^{2x}\equiv 1 \pmod 8$ and $3^{2x+1}\equiv 3 \pmod 8.$ Here, since $b=0$ doesn't work, for $b\geqslant1$, RHS $\equiv -5 \equiv 3 \pmod 8$, so $b$ has to be odd, and we can easily observe that only $b=1,3$ can satisfy, (also from here we get that $a$ has to be even), hence we're through with this case.

*Case 2*: $\boxed{\min(a,b)\geqslant3}.$ $a$ and $b$ are unequal from above
\begin{align*}
\implies\min(a,b)\leqslant v_3\left(3^a+2\cdot3^b\right)
&=v_3\left(2^{a+b+1}-1\right)
\\&=v_3\left(4^{\tfrac{a+b+1}{2}}-1\right)
\\&=1+v_3\left(\frac{a+b+1}{2}\right)-(*)
\\&\leqslant1+v_3(\max(a,b)).
\end{align*}
Since, $a,b$ are different, so $|a-b|\geqslant1$ and as $\max(a,b) = \frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$, so the desired in the last step above; and $(*)$ follows from LTE, as $3|4-1$, $3\nmid 4,1$ and $3\ne 2$.

> This is another motivation for turning the problem towards $\frac{a+b+1}{2}$.

Now,
$$\implies \max(a,b) \geqslant 3^{\min(a,b)-1}.$$
Next, as $\max(a,b)+\min(a,b)=a+b$, so
$$2^{\max(a,b)+\min(a,b)+1}=2^{a+b+1}=3^a+2\cdot3^b+1>3^{\max(a,b)}$$
$$\implies2^{\min(a,b)+1} > \left(\frac 32\right)^{\max(a,b)} \geqslant \left(\frac 32\right)^{3^{\min(a,b)-1}}.$$
which isn't true for $\min(a,b) \geqslant 3.$ Thus, no solution in this case.

So now, the only possible solutions here are: $\boxed{(a,b)=(2,1);(2,3)}$ and $\boxed{n=3,5}.$
$$
\begin{cases}
n=3:m^2+2\cdot3^2=m(2^4-1)\implies m^2-15m+54=0\implies m=6\text{ or }9.\\
n=5:m^2+2\cdot3^5=m(2^6-1)\implies m^2-63m+162=0\implies m=9\text{ or }54.
\end{cases}
$$
So, the solutions are: $$\boxed{(m,n)=(6,3);(9,3);(9,5);(54,5).}$$

> I did this problem with a nudge from v_Enhance, as I was stuck at the later part of the problem, where some relation between $\min(a,b)$ and $\max(a,b)$ helps to get out, through some contradiction etc; and rest of all the steps are pretty usual, just that formalizing in the form of cases $\le 2$, $\ge 3$, instead of randomly putting inputs and taking care of obtained values all the time.

Comment: Hey Srijon , Nice solution! +1 and welcome to MSE!

Comment: Hey @SunainaPati! Thanks